# Is Redux.js a sufficient way to separate data from view in a React.js/Node.js hybrid application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I am quite new to web programming. I've started developing a single-page web application using React.js with a Node server.
I've read the tutorial, played with boilerplates, and quickly I understood React would take care only of the view aspect. So I tried to put my data-processing functions with the *export* keyword in a JavaScript file so I could use them in my React components. But that way was pretty "dirty" and it didn't feel satisfying at all.

Then I looked for a way to effectively separate the model and the controller from the view, so that I could completely change the GUI with little effort, and thus allow the project to grow and multiple people to work on it at the same time.

I've came across [this article](https://medium.com/@cabot_solutions/flux-the-react-js-application-architecture-a-comprehensive-study-fd2585d06483) explaining the Flux architecture, and I saw a major implementation to use with React.js was Redux.js. I was quite surprised that I didn't see it at first, and now I wonder how much frameworks one has to use when working with JavaScript and Web.

My question is simple : is Redux.js all I need to effectively separate data, treatments and GUI components ? Or did I miss something else ? Are there any other major architectures you would recommend ?

Many thanks,

Comment: Redux is good enough....have a look at: https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list

Comment: Don't use Redux unless you need them. Check out this article from the creator of Redux. https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux is generally used to contain all the data that your app needs. It acts like a store which can pass the required data to the components that actually needs the data. For example, if you need a particular data fetched from an ajax request to be distributed among two components, then redux is a perfect fit. Whether you need redux depends on how your app is structured. If you have an app with a large number of components and most of these require data from your server or api, I'd suggest you go with redux. Once you learn it, it's incredibly simple. And yes, redux is all you need to separate data from ui. To get a nicely formatted structure, put together all your ajax requests under a folder and export it so that you can call it from the ui component. And when you receive the data pass the payload to the redux store which will automatically pass it to all the components which are connected to that particular reducer. For details on how to connect react with redux, check out their documentation: 
https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react
Remember not to confuse the state mentioned in redux with the state in react. Redux state refers to the application state. Do check it out and if doesn't work for you, another alternative would be flux.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I had a look at Redux's doc as well as konekoya's link and I finally decided not to use it. Indeed the limitations are too important regarding the need for the project, and a full React approach seems to be enough. I still have other questions but I will take a look at existing posts and eventually create a new one if needed. Thanks for the answers !

Comment: The new version of React has a context api which is really useful for handling data in your app and it works similar to redux https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html . Here's a video to get started if you need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLJN4JfniH4